# Error: Module Not Found on Discord Bot's Command Handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, sequelize.js

first and foremost, I'm very new to this. I've been following the tutorials at the [Discord.js Site](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/), with the goal being to make a discord bot for the Play by Post DnD server I'm in where everyone wants to gain experience via word count.

I mention I'm new to this because this is my first hands-on experience with Javascript, a lot of the terminology goes over my head.

So, the problem seems to be where I've broken away from the tutorial. It goes over command handlers, which I want to stick with because it seems to be good practice and easier to work with down the line when something most breaks (And I know it will). But the tutorial for Databases (Currency/Sequelizer) doesn't really touch on command handlers beyond "Maintain references".

But that's enough foreword, the problem is in trying to get a command that checks the database for a player's current experience points and level.

I have the seemingly relevant files organized with the index.js and dbObjects.js together, a models folder for the Users, and LevelUp(CurrencyShop in the tutorial) and a separate folder for the Commands like the problematic one, xpcheck.js

I can get the command to function without *breaking*, using the following,

```js
const { Client, Collection, Formatters, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const experience = new  Collection();
const level = new Collection();

Reflect.defineProperty(experience, 'getBalance', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = experience.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(level, 'getBalance', {
    /* eslint-disable-next-line func-name-matching */
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = level.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 1;
    },
});

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('xpcheck')
        .setDescription('Your current Experience and Level'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const target = interaction.options.getUser('user') ?? interaction.user;

        return interaction.reply(`${target.tag} is level ${level.getBalance(target.id)} and has ${experience.getBalance(target.id)} experience.`);;
    },
};
```

The problem is that the command doesn't reference the database. It returns default values (1st level, 0 exp) every time.

I tried getting the command to reference the database, one of many attempts being this one;

```js
const { Client, Collection, Formatters, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { Users, LevelUp } = require('./DiscordBot/dbObjects.js');


module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('xpcheck')
        .setDescription('Your current Experience and Level'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const experience = new  Collection();
        const level = new Collection();
        const target = interaction.options.getUser('user') ?? interaction.user;

        return interaction.reply(`${target.tag} is level ${level.getBalance(target.id)} and has ${experience.getBalance(target.id)} experience.`);;
    },
};
```

However, when I run node deploy-commands.js, it throws

> Error: Cannot find module './DiscordBot/dbObjects.js'

It does the same thing even if I remove the `/DiscordBot`, or any other way I've attempted to make a constant for it. I'm really uncertain what I should do to alleviate this issue.

My file structure, for reference, is:

```
v DiscordBot

  v commands
     xpcheck.js

  v models
     LevelUp.js
     UserItems.js
     Users.js

  dbInit.js
  dbObjects.js
  deploy-commands.js
  index.js
```

Comment: As a note, I am fairly certain the issue lies in dbObjects.js not being 'behind'(I'm unsure of the correct terminology) the Commands folder, but I have no idea what I could do about that.

Comment: Your trying to require a file that's not in that folder / requiring a folder that does not exist, Can you edit the question with the your file structure (like how your files are) most likely your using a wrong path (maybe check if DiscordBot/dbObjects.js is what you need, maybe ur trying to do ./dbObjects.js since the root file is not needed)

Comment: I know it's not on in that particular folder, it's above/before it, but I don't know if I can put it in the commands folder or a subfolder and still have it do what it needs to do with other bits of the code.

Also, the file structure is now in the post ^-^

Comment: from your code i get it your trying to require "dbObjects.js" from xpcheck.js command / file. so ye what i said above was correct (just need a little fix)

in a path you dont need to reference the base path (ex: DiscordBot)

the path you want is : "../dbObjects.js", since the file is in the root / base directory and your requiring it from xpcheck.js which is in "command" folder

Comment: So- '..' is the key there?

Comment: replace this line in xpcheck.js and `const { Users, LevelUp } = require('./DiscordBot/dbObjects.js');` with `const { Users, LevelUp } = require('../dbObjects.js');` and pls confirm it works or not : ). (make sure to correct other places too)

_saw your comment while writing this_

Sort of, i suggest your learn how paths work in node.js which will make this easier (this should work in xpcheck.js file while it might not work on a file thats not in a folder, it depends)

Comment: It did work! And as I said, I am learning, and I couldn't seem to find a solution on google. What I can say is that with a single period ('./File Name') it will work on the same folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, the problem was simple, the solution simpler.

Correcting

```
const { Users, LevelUp } = require('./dbObjects.js');
```

to

```
const { Users, LevelUp } = require('../dbObjects.js');
```

allows it to search the main directory for the requisite file.